# Transformation between different hyperbolic plane coordinate systems

Tags: complex-analysis, coordinate-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, mobius-transformation

On the hyperbolic plane, we can use 'polar' coordinates $(\rho,\tau)$ giving the metric
$$ds^2 =d\rho^2 + \sinh^2(\rho) d\tau^2,$$
or, in the upper-half plane model, we can use the 'Cartesian' coordinates $(x,y)$, giving the metric:
$$ ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}. $$
I'm wondering if there's an explicit transformation between these coordinates. What seems to work is:
$$
x=i\coth(\rho) e^{i\tau}, \quad y = \frac{1}{\sinh(\rho)}e^{i\tau},
$$
however, then $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers, whereas I would think that they should both be real to interpret them as the real and imaginary parts of $z = x+iy$ on the complex upper-half plane. Is there a simpler transformation that you are aware of such that $x$ and $y$ are real?

Comment: Just to verify: that $\rho,\tau$ metric is incomplete on the disc, and I believe it instead should be regarded as a metric on the entire polar coordinate plane. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit my question by replacing 'disk' by 'plane'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer above, I've worked out a solution, for who is interested.

The relation between disk polar coordinates and plane polar coordinates can be found by requiring:
$$ds^2 = \frac{4}{(1-r^2)^2}(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2) = d\rho^2 + \sinh^2\rho d\tau^2$$
This is solved by:
$$
\theta = \tau, \quad r = \tanh\frac{\rho}{2}
$$
Then, we map the disk coordinate $w = re^{i\theta}$ to the upper-half plane via the Cayley transformation:
$$
z= i\frac{1-w}{1+w} = i \frac{1-r^2-2i \Im(w)}{1+r^2 +2\Re(w)}
$$
Writing $z=x+iy$, we then see that:
$$
x = \frac{2\Im(w)}{1+r^2 +2\Re(w)}, \quad y = \frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2 +2\Re(w)}
$$
It's clear that the unit circle ($r=1$) is mapped to the real axis $(y=0)$.
Now plugging in $\Re(w) = r\cos\theta$ and $\Im(w) = r\sin\theta$, as well as our expressions for $\theta$ and $r$ in terms of $\tau$ and $\rho$, we find:
$$
x = \frac{2\tanh\frac{\rho}{2} \sin\tau}{1+2\tanh\frac{\rho}{2}\cos\tau + \tanh^2\frac{\rho}{2}}, \quad y = \frac{1}{\cosh\rho+\cos\tau\sinh\rho}
$$
Since the upper-half plane has a PSL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ isometry, we can probably find a nicer expression for $x$ and $y$ after a suitable PSL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ transformation $z\to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, $ad-bc=1$, but I haven't tried that yet.
To check that this transformation has the right behaviour at the boundary, let's take the limit $\rho \to \infty$:
$$
\lim_{\rho\to\infty}y(\rho,\tau) = 0,
$$
which makes sense since the boundary should be at $y=0$. Furthermore, the expression for $x$ simplifies a lot at the boundary:
$$
\lim_{\rho\to\infty}x(\rho,\tau) = \tan\frac{\tau}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest an outline for deriving a transformation, breaking the problem into steps, where the [Poincare disc model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric#Metric_and_volume_element_on_the_Poincar%C3%A9_disk) sits intermediate between the polar coordinate plane model and the upper half plane model. The metric on the Poincare disc model is given by
$$ds^2 = \frac{4}{\left( 1 - (x^2+y^2)\right)^2} (dx^2 + dy^2)
$$
You can easily convert this formula into polar coordinates on the unit disc, using the ordinary Euclidean--polar coordinate transformations. Noticing that the Poincare disc formula is conformal with respect to the Euclidean metric (i.e. of the form $g(x,y) (dx^2 + dy^2)$), and noticing the rotational symmetry of the Poincare disc metric, you should expect to get a metric of the form
$$ds^2 = f(r)^2 (dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2)
$$
where that bit in parentheses is the usual formula for the Euclidean metric expressed in polar coordinates. Of course you'll probably want to work out an explicit formula for $f(r)$; by inspection it ought to be $f(r) = \frac{4}{(1-r^2)^2}$.

There is a [well known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric#Conformal_map_of_plane_to_disk) that relates the Poincare disc metric (expressed in a complex $w=x+iy$ coordinate) to the upper half plane model (also expressed in a complex $z=x+iy$ coordinate), and it is easy to derive for yourself:
$$w = \frac{iz+1}{z+i}
$$
Perhaps you want to rewrite this in $x,y$ coordinates.

So what remains is to convert the Poincare disc polar coordinate model into the planar polar coordinate model. The circular symmetry of both models suggest that you first set $\theta=\tau$, and then work out the transformation of the radial coordinate $\rho = g(r)$, $g : [0,1) \to [0,\infty)$.